# Column menus open in wrong position in IE9

Tags: angular-ui-grid

The menus for sorting columns are being positioned relative to a higher level container div, rather than relative to the containing grid cell. See attached. I have tried to change the absolute positioning of '.ui-grid-column-menu' to relative, which has no effect. Does anyone know of a fix for this?
[image: ui-grid column menu being positioned incorrectly in IE9]

Comment: Hi @chrisjm did you find the issue? I'm having the same problem... thank you!!

Comment: For the time being, I have disabled the column sorting menu as I have been unable to find a solution to the issue. Since the columns still sort when you click the headings, you only lose the ability to directly select the sorting option and whether or not to hide the column. This is acceptable in my application's current requirements.